# Determine if bash/zsh/etc. is running under Midnight Commander

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, mc

Simple question. I'd like to know how to tell whether the current shell is running as a `mc` subshell or not. If it is, I'd like to enter a degraded mode without some features `mc` can't handle.

In particular, I'd like this to

- Be as portable as possible
- Not rely on anything outside the shell and basic universal external commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's not documented in the man page, a quick experiment shows that `mc` sets two environment variables: `$MC_TMPDIR` and `$MC_SID`. (It also sets `$HISTCONTROL`, but that's not specific to `mc`; it affects the behavior of bash, and could have been set by something other than `mc`.)

If you don't want to depend on undocumented features, you can always set an environment variable yourself. For example, in bash:

```
mc() { MC_IS_RUNNING=1 command mc "$@" ; }
```

Entering a "degraded mode" is another matter; I'm not sure how you'd do that. I don't know of any way in bash to disable specified features. You could disable selected built-in commands by defining functions that override them. What features do you have in mind?

Comment: Nah, I know how I'll do the degraded mode. (Remove some stuff from the prompt in .bashrc, for instance). I'll check this and see if it works.